# how to package Backbone artifacts and what are best technologies for hosting them?

Tags: backbone.js

I am starting on Backbone.js and I am looking into ways I can modularize features into some kind of plugin/package/lib that could be reused by importing into html page with 'script' tag. What are you using for packaging Backbonejs artifacts? How do you version them? and where do you host these packages?

so far, I am thinking to use gradle to compile views, modules, collections and routes into one js file. has anyone gone this route?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to take a look at requirejs (http://requirejs.org/)

Comment: Thank you Mallim. I decided to go with Gradle js plugin http://vimeo.com/44848776 Will see how far it will get me. If not, i will look into RequireJS